# IronPython 2.6.1 for .NET 4.0 RC targeting Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, ironpython

Since the 2.6.1 .NET 4.0 RC release of IronPython (found @ http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/40146) does not include Silverlight binaries I am wondering if anyone has had any success getting it working themselves. I'd assume it would not be too hard to recompile the source against Silverlight but I can't seem to locate it on Codeplex.

EDIT:

Per the IronPython team, Silverlight 4 is not yet a stable release so no fully compatible binaries have been released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's something to do with how Silverlight 4 has not been released yet and there is no end-user runtime for it yet? See http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4/.

Comment: After having been in touch with one of the coordinators of the IronPython project this seems to be the reasoning. Once I clarify with him I will make a note here and mark the question answered.